# Retrofit does not send body to server in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

When I use post-man and send empty data to the server, I receive this response:

[image: post-man screen shot]

So, For send image file to the server, I use retofit2 and do the following:

First I create a data model class:

```
public class UploadProfileResponseModel {
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private int status;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Then, Create an API interface:

```
public interface UploadProfileApi {
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Multipart
    @POST("imageupload")
    Call<UploadProfileResponseModel> uploadFile(
            @Header("x-access-token") String token,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
            @Part("image") RequestBody imageFile);
}
```

And then create a Network Client class for setup retrofit:

```
public class NetworkClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Urls.BASE_URL_API)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

So, Finally in my Fragment, I Crop an image with [Android Image Cropper Library](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) And updload file with returned Uri:

```
private void sendParams(Uri uri) {

    Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(context);
    UploadProfileApi uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(UploadProfileApi.class);

    File file = new File(FileUtil.getPath(uri, context));
    RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

    MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
    RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "image-type");

    Call<UploadProfileResponseModel> call = uploadAPIs.uploadFile(sharedPreferences.getString("token", ""), part, description);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadProfileResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UploadProfileResponseModel> call, Response<UploadProfileResponseModel> response) {
            UploadProfileResponseModel model = response.body();
            if (model.getStatus() == 1)
                Snackbar.make(view, model.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Snackbar.make(view, model.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UploadProfileResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

And this is FileUtil class that returns the path of Uri:

```
public class FileUtil {

@SuppressLint(value = "NewApi")
public static String getPath(Uri uri, Context context) {
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            if (id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                return id.replaceFirst("raw:", "");
            }
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            switch (type) {
                case "image":
                    uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
                case "video":
                    uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
                case "audio":
                    uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
        };
        try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)) {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("on getPath", "Exception", e);
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

So, When I send the image file to the server, I receive this message **image in body is required** in Snackbar. This means that the image is not sent to the server.

Where is my work wrong? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you check returned Uri is null or not in **onActivityResult**?

Comment: @Sajjadjavadi yes, I set `imageView.setImageURI(result.getUri());` and it showing that Uri.